# Impact of spell checkers on prescriptive language reform

Tags: orthography, dictionary, prescriptivism

I had a story about prescriptive language reform, specifically about the Real Academia Española and its decision to change the spelling of *puzzle* (pronounced /ˈpuθle/ in Spain) in the 21st edition (1992) of its Diccionario de la lengua española to *puzle* in the 22nd edition (2001).  They did not reform *pizza* to *piza*.

My story was that this had failed to gain much traction as most Spaniards would only see the word written on the corner of a jigsaw puzzle box (typically made by the German company Ravensburger) and would have no reason to look up its spelling. [Google nGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=puzle%2Cpuzzle&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=es-2012&smoothing=1) seemed to confirm the continued dominance of the original spelling a decade after the reform.  But [looking again later](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=puzle%2Cpuzzle&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=es-2019&smoothing=1), the change seems to have largely taken place, undermining my story.

Is this a result of automated spell-checkers eventually following the official dictionary reform, so changing the usage proportions in the corpus that Google uses?  Does this sort of thing affect other languages too?

Comment: Pizza's double z is pronounced in Spanish, similar to the Italian. The double z of puzzle is not. The RAE does as it likes to adapt words to the genius of the language so the change makes sense.